# How to remove the 'seconds' of Pandas dataframe index?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

Given a dataframe with time series that looks like this:

```
                      Close
2015-02-20 14:00:00  1200.1
2015-02-20 14:10:00  1199.8
2015-02-21 14:00:00  1199.3
2015-02-21 14:10:00  1199.0
2015-02-22 14:00:00  1198.4
2015-02-22 14:10:00  1199.7
```

How can I get rid of the 'seconds' of the index so it looks like this:

```
                   Close
2015-02-20 14:00  1200.1
2015-02-20 14:10  1199.8
2015-02-21 14:00  1199.3
2015-02-21 14:10  1199.0
2015-02-22 14:00  1198.4
2015-02-22 14:10  1199.7
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `map` and `strftime` like this:

```
df.index =df.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```