# Remove 'seconds' and 'minutes' from a Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Given a dataframe like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
{'Date' : pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5, freq='3675S'),
 'Num' : np.random.rand(5)})
                 Date       Num
0 2011-01-01 00:00:00  0.580997
1 2011-01-01 01:01:15  0.407332
2 2011-01-01 02:02:30  0.786035
3 2011-01-01 03:03:45  0.821792
4 2011-01-01 04:05:00  0.807869
```

I would like to remove the 'minutes' and 'seconds' information.

The following (mostly stolen from: [How to remove the 'seconds' of Pandas dataframe index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664430/how-to-remove-the-seconds-of-pandas-dataframe-index)) works okay,

```
df = df.assign(Date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')))
                 Date       Num
0 2011-01-01 00:00:00  0.580997
1 2011-01-01 01:00:00  0.407332
2 2011-01-01 02:00:00  0.786035
3 2011-01-01 03:00:00  0.821792
4 2011-01-01 04:00:00  0.807869
```

but it feels strange to convert a datetime to a string then back to a datetime.  Is there a way to do this more directly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## [`dt.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html)

This is how it should be done... use [`dt.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html)

```
df.assign(Date=df.Date.dt.round('H'))

                 Date       Num
0 2011-01-01 00:00:00  0.577957
1 2011-01-01 01:00:00  0.995748
2 2011-01-01 02:00:00  0.864013
3 2011-01-01 03:00:00  0.468762
4 2011-01-01 04:00:00  0.866827
```

***OLD ANSWER***

One approach is to set the index and use `resample`

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('H').last().reset_index()

                 Date       Num
0 2011-01-01 00:00:00  0.577957
1 2011-01-01 01:00:00  0.995748
2 2011-01-01 02:00:00  0.864013
3 2011-01-01 03:00:00  0.468762
4 2011-01-01 04:00:00  0.866827
```

Another alternative is to strip the `date` and `hour` components

```
df.assign(
    Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date.dt.date) +
         pd.to_timedelta(df.Date.dt.hour, unit='H'))

                 Date       Num
0 2011-01-01 00:00:00  0.577957
1 2011-01-01 01:00:00  0.995748
2 2011-01-01 02:00:00  0.864013
3 2011-01-01 03:00:00  0.468762
4 2011-01-01 04:00:00  0.866827
```

Comment: Turns out `dt.floor` worked better for my case although I expect `dt.round` is better in general.  -Thanks

Comment: ATTENTION: the round of 2030-01-01 21:54:00 is 2030-01-01 22:00:00 and NOT 2030-01-01 21:00:00 --- to do this use dt.floor

Comment: Alternatively: df.Date = df.Date.dt.floor('H')

Answer (score 2):

Other solution could be this :

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.Date = df.Date.apply(lambda x: datetime(x.year, x.month, x.day, x.hour))
```

Comment: Just to add, I needed pd.datetime but otherwise this worked perfectly.