# How to get rid of milliseconds for datetime in Python

Tags: pandas, datetime, time

I have my DateTime like this

```
0       2021-02-01 00:01:02.327
1       2021-02-01 00:01:21.445
2       2021-02-01 00:01:31.912
3       2021-02-01 00:01:32.600
4       2021-02-01 00:02:08.920
```

However, I would like them in the format of %Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S. I have tried with these methods, but they did not make any difference.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.time
```

or

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Another quick question is if I would like to add a new column named 'Time', could I please have them only have the information only in %H:%M:%S from Date column?

```
0       00:01:02.327
1       00:01:21.445
2       00:01:31.912
3       00:01:32.600
4       00:02:08.920
```

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/q/43400331/10197418

Comment: Thank you I also have a go with this attempt, for some reason resample is not working. This is what I have done df = df.set_index('Date').resample('S').last().reset_index(). However, I got result like this Exception has occurred: TypeError
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) by seconds:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.floor('S')
```

Comment: `round` is another option, in case milliseconds should be considered and not just truncated