# reduce milliseconds precision python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, milliseconds

I have this timestamp

```
2023-07-12 21:12:21.940000
```

After converting it using :

```
df_snowflake['last_activity']=df_snowflake['last_activity'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I want to reduce the milliseconds precision and get the next datetime :

```
2023-07-12 21:12:21.940
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66636656/how-to-get-rid-of-milliseconds-for-datetime-in-python. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html

Comment: Maybe with pandas is better, try something like this: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.time`

Comment: "*reduce the milliseconds precision*" - to what other precision? Also, what's the desired data type here, a string? A pandas datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format strings to achieve that.

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2023-07-12 21:12:21.94000", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(f"{dt:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}.{dt.microsecond // 1000:03d}")
```

You can also use string comprehensions like `dt[:-3]`, however in this case you won't be able to deal with 0 milliseconds.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64167781/13135739)

Comment: it's much easier here to use [datetime.isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) with keyword `timespec="milliseconds"`. However, I think OP is using pandas, so this might not apply.

Comment: Actually I have used 'dt[:-3]' and I am satisfied by the result